# Is there a special name for matrices consist of repeated unit vectors?

Tags: matrices, terminology

For example this one:
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might call'em a [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition): $\pmatrix{1 &0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}\otimes\pmatrix{1 &1&1}$
of [matrices with entries from the Boolean domain B = {0, 1}.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix)